# Have two generals ever agreed to fight one on one to avoid a battle?

Tags: battle

In fiction, there's a scene sometimes occur where 2 armies are facing each other in preparation for battle, but the leaders parlay and agree to fight one on one to determine the outcome with minimum bloodshed. Has this ever actually happened in history?

Comment: This has been covered [before](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/34918/16951)

Comment: The linked answer has examples of combats between heros (hand-picked warriors, like Achilles in the Iliad or the 3 twins in the Roman legend), not kings/generals. Except for the Indian example where 2 chiefs fought. So I do not think it is answered

Comment: BTW: the 3x3 brother combat in Roman legend is related, among others, by St Augustine (in the city of god, when he comments on the Roman foundational legends). And, there is a fresco sequence (like a comics, with many frames) about this battle in a ceiling inside the Roman Capitole (the one with Michelangelo equestrian statue in the front)

Comment: Nearby Crowheart Butte was the site of a battle between the Crow and Shoshone American Indian tribes in 1866. According to legend, following a five-day battle for rights to the hunting grounds in the Wind River Range, Chief Washakie of the Shoshone and Chief Big Robber of the Crow agreed to a duel, with the winner gaining the rights to the Wind River hunting grounds. Chief Washakie eventually prevailed, but he was so impressed with the courage of his opponent, that rather than scalp him, he instead cut out his heart  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowheart,_Wyoming

Comment: According to the Russian Primary Chronicle, such a duel was agreed to by Mstislav the Brave, Prince of Tmutarakan and Kasog Prince Rededia in 1022 instead of having their armies fight.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_combat