# Has a head of state ever actually killed another in battle?

Tags: war

In "historical" or fantasy movies you often see the two enemy leaders fighting directly in the middle of the battle, mainly to allow for dialogue.

I know that leaders have had their enemies executed after the battle - there are multiple examples of executions by the Mongols. And some may have fought in single combat against each other. But I'm only interested in battlefield combat.

Has anything like this ever happened? I mean, it seems spectacularly unlikely.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any examples of single combat between kings/generals ending a war?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34918/are-there-any-examples-of-single-combat-between-kings-generals-ending-a-war)

Comment: Clovis I king of the Franks did kill Ragnachar king of Cambrai with an axe, but it was after the battle was over and Ragnachar had his hands tied behind his back and was already a prisoner, so i don't know if this counts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnachar

Comment: @JohnStrachan counts or not, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @CGCampbell Apologies. But i respect voters appear to be extremely strict regarding definitions and I was hoping for some clarification from mike1952 as to whether this counts or not.

Comment: While related, the suggested duplicate differs sufficiently from this that they shouldn't be treated as duplicates to close. The earlier question was about single combat between leaders to avoid a battle (and conclude the war). This question merely requires that one head of state killed another on the battlefield.

Comment: Would the claimed killing of Cyrus the Younger by Tissaphernes qualify?  (As related in Xenophon's "Anabasis".)

Comment: Well, Alexander tried to have a go at Darius but Darius ran away. And Cyrus the Younger tried to pull a similar stunt off hut got killed in the process.

Comment: @mike1952  I think it would be better for you to refer to the leaders of the protagonists and the leaders of the antagonists in movies instead of the good leaders and the bad leaders in those movies.  Movie makers have ways to make the audience think that the protagonists are the heroes and the antagonists are the villains, not matter what the facts might be.  Thus different movies about the same conflict can depict different sides as the heroes and the villains.

Comment: The *accepted* answer reveals to me: justCal, OP, answer-writer MAGolding and myself, we are all in agreement that this is a duplicate. Voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some examples, from my answer to:

[Are there any examples of single combat between kings & generals?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34918/are-there-any-examples-of-single-combat-between-kings-generals-ending-a-war/34927#34927%5B1%5D)

> In 161 BC Sinhalese King Dutugamunu riding his elephant Kandula defeated and killed Tamil King Ellalan or Elara on his elephant Maha Pamata ("big rock").
>
> Simamese King Naresuan killed Burmese Crown Prince Mingyi Swa on elephant back in 1593.
>
> Adolf, Count of Nassau was elected King of the Romans in April 1292. In 1298 the electors declared Adolf deposed and Duke Albert of Austria elected in his place. Adolf and Albert fought at the battle of Gollheim on 2 July 1298 and Albert personally killed Adolf.
>
> At the Battle of Antioch-on-the Meander in 1211 Emperor Theodore Lascaris is said to have personally killed Kaykhusraw I, Sultan of Rum.

Other similar examples can be found at [historum.com](https://historum.com/threads/single-combat-in-the-seventh-century.181793/%5B2%5D)

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm surprised there are any, but much happier for knowing that 
a) it has happened
b) it's rare, especially if you aren't on an elephant.

Answer (score 3):

Roman history provides us with two more examples, one of which is fictional and the other reasonably trustworthy. Quoting the wikipedia entry on *[Spolia Opima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spolia_opima)*

> The spolia opima ("rich spoils") were the armour, arms, and other
> effects that an ancient Roman general stripped from the body of an
> opposing commander slain in single combat.
>
> For the majority of the city's existence, the Romans recognized only
> three instances when spolia opima were taken. The precedent was
> imagined in Rome's mythical history, which tells that in 752 BC
> Romulus defeated and stripped Acron, king of the Caeninenses,
> following the Rape of the Sabine Women.[...] The third and most historically grounded occurred before the
> Second Punic War when Marcus Claudius Marcellus (consul 222 BC)
> stripped the Celtic warrior Viridomarus, a king of the Gaesatae.

So we have Romulus and Marcellus. I skipped the third guy because careful reading and cross-comparison shows he was not consul at the time he achieved his feat and so not (even co-) head of state.